# Validating other fields depending on select

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have this in my view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label> Condition Target </label>
    <input type="text" name="ConditionTarget1" id="ConditionTarget1"/>
    <input type="text" name="ConditionTarget2" id="ConditionTarget2"/>
    <br/>

    <label> Condition Object </label>
    <select name="ConditionObject" id="ConditionObject">
        <option value="1"> Condition 1 </option>
        <option value="2"> Condition 2 </option>
    </select>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

In my controller (for example):

```
public ActionResult Validate(int value)
{
    return Json(value == 1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I want that when conditionobject changes, Validate server method should be called and depending on result conditiontarget text fields must become required (in this case if option 2 is selected). I tried jQuery remote validation but it validates select itself. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#ConditionObject').change(function(){
       $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "servercode.asp",
         data:this.val();
        success:function(data)
       {
         if(data==1)
        {
           $('#ConditionTarget1').addClass('required');//add required validation ,sample only
        }
      }
    });
 });
```

then during validation check ConditionTarget1 has got any validation

```
$('input:submit').click(function(){

 if($('#ConditionTarget1').hasClass('required'))
  {
     alert('oops validation required');
      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to call server side method ?
Try this:

```
$('#ConditionObject').on("change",function(){
    if($(this).val() == 1)
    {
        $('#ConditionTarget1').addClass("Required");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#ConditionTarget1').removeClass("Required");
    }
});
```

On submit: `<input id="submitForm" type="submit"/>`

```
$("#submitForm").on("click", function(event){
  if($('#ConditionTarget1').hasClass("Required"))
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I really have to call server side method. It's more complex code written in controller action, I just simplified